# delete level 1 array search by value on level 2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I delete a row of array (Level 1) by searching for the duplicate value in array (Level 2)?

```
$array = array(
   0 => array('name' => 'haha1', 'dateline' => '2014-07-1 00:00:00', 'toid' => '1')
   1 => array('name' => 'haha2', 'dateline' => '2014-07-1 00:00:00', 'toid' => '2')
   2 => array('name' => 'haha3', 'dateline' => '2014-07-1 00:00:00', 'toid' => '1')
   3 => array('name' => 'haha4', 'dateline' => '2014-07-1 00:00:00', 'toid' => '3')
);
```

delete the row $array[2] due to $array[2]['toid'] is duplicate to $array[0]['toid'].
keep the $array[0] but remove $array[2]

I tried foreach inside foreach like the following, but I think I have used them in the wrong way:

```
$container = array(); //The Container for none duplicated array

foreach($array as $key => $var){
  foreach($container as $k => $v){
     if(!array_search($var['toid'], $v['toid'])){
        $container[] = $var;
     }
  }
}
```

Another question:  the record is fetch from MySQL database, other than the array way, is possible to fetch none duplicate row in MySQL?

Is it possible to do it using a MySQL query and which solution is faster/prefer?

The SQL is structured as follows:

```
'id' => auto_increment, int(11)
'name' => varchar(255)
'dateline' => datetime,
'toid' => int(11)
```

How can I fetch all none duplicated 'toid' field row order by the 'dateline'?

Comment: For your first question, tell us what you have tried, what it did etc.  Your second question is not particularly answerable as you provide no information as to your MySQL structure / your MySQL SELECT.  There are various methods to get rid of duplicates within MySQL i.e. GROUP BY, but again you need to tell us more about what you've tried.

Comment: sry forget to tell about the mysql structure,

i had tried using foreach inside foreach, will edit the question now

Comment: thanks, i tried the group by, and did what i want exactly, learned something new

Comment: You do need to be careful with GROUP BY though because the non-grouped / non-aggregate columns aren't guaranteed to always return values from the same rows each time you select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$data=array();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
        $tmp=array();
    $data =  array_unique(array_merge($data,$array[$i]));
}
```

Now duplicate entries have been removed.
Now create a multidimensional array

```
$output=array();
$tmp = &$output;
foreach($data as &$val){
  if(strpos($val,'level') !==false ){
     if (!is_array($tmp)){
          $tmp = array();
      }
      $tmp = &$tmp[$val];

  }else{
    $tmp[] = $val;
  }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
exit();
```